# Comma delimited class property assignment problem

Tags: c#

I'm loading a comma delimited file into a list, no problems here.  Except the last segment is separated by a semicolon of which I need to put into an array that has a property name.  In this case Sequence and Rotation.  The code below works except giving it a property name.

Any advice would be much appreciated.  I've kept the code below to bare-bones to avoid clutter.

Example CSV File: `Bar001,P02;90`

```
class PartDetail 
{
 public string Description 
 {
  get;
  set;
 }
 public string[] BottomEdge 
 {
  get;
  set;
 }


 public class SpecificDetails << < I want to use this class to specify the property name. {
  public string Sequence 
  {
   get;
   set;
  }
  public string Rotation 
  {
   get;
   set;
  }
 }

 public PartDetail(string line) 
 {
  string[] parts = line.Split(',');
  this.Description = parts[0];
  this.BottomEdge = parts[1].Split(';'); << It 's here where I am struggling.
 }
}
```

Comment: So do you want to store `P02` in BottomEdge and `90` in another variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do the trick

```
class PartDetail 
{
 ....
 //create an instance of your SpecificDetails class
 SpecificDetails Details = new SpecificDetails();
 ...
 public PartDetail(string line) 
 {
  string[] parts = line.Split(',');
  this.Description = parts[0];
  this.BottomEdge = parts[1].Split(';'); 

  //assign the value to the properties of the "Details" instance
  this.Details.Sequence = this.BottomEdge[0];
  this.Details.Rotation = this.BottomEdge[1];
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `line.Split(new char[]{ ',', ';'})` and just pick the last index of the returned array to be the closing segment of your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Dot net has a built in CSV parser, so there is no need to roll your own (https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/built-in-net-csv-parser/)

```
using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(path))
{
parser.CommentTokens = new string[] { "#" };
parser.SetDelimiters(new string[] { ";" });
parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

// Skip over header line.
parser.ReadLine();

while (!parser.EndOfData)
{
    string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();

}
}
```

Once parsed, you are left with the semicolon problem, which can easily be solved with string.Split.